# Equation numbering in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The fact is, that in official documentation [Jupyter - motivating examples](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html#Equation-Numbering-and-References) stands

> Equation numbering and referencing will be available in a future version of the Jupyter notebook.

I know there is a lot of discussion about this topic. There are some people who claim to solve this issue with some workarounds.

But for ordinary user it is hard to understand the workarounds, or how dirty/useful the hacks really are.

So my questions are:

1. what means the "available in future version"? Does it mean something like "new month/year" or something like "probably never because it is too impossible"?
2. If any of the workarounds provided on the Internet safe for a human consumption? I mean is it worthy? Because it is possible to use Sphinx or something else for creation of tutorials, it will be more work, but it will be more work that implementing some hacks, installing plug-ins and so on?

Note: For somebody it could seems to be a question requiring opinion based answer, but I am pretty sure it is not. Any advice can help me (or others users) to make a good/bad decision.

Comment: It's partly opinionated, partly unanswerable. #1 can only be answered by the jupyter devs, if anybody. #2 is way too broad, and a request for off-site resources. I'm afraid none of your question is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you for response. I get your point. But still I think this question is legitimate because it seems that too many people need to know the same thing. And even if the question is unanswerable today, it can be answered acceptably in future.

Comment: I don't have *too* strong feelings about it (hence no downvotes or closevotes on your question yet:P), so we'll see what others think. Just wanted to give you a heads-up:)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe that essentially all information relevant to this question can be found in this long Github issue [thread](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4113).

The conversation there has been ongoing for (at this moment) <s>3.5</s> <s>6.5</s> 8 years and is still active.  Important highlights:

- You can very simply turn on numbering by executing a cell with the following content:

  ```py
  %%javascript
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
      TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
  });
  ```
- There is an [extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/equation-numbering) for equation numbering.
- Developer minrk has suggested that this extension is the right approach and could be merged into master (but the functionality would be turned off by default).

To install the extension via `pip`:

```sh
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

To install [the extensions](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/):

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

After using **one** of the ways to install provided above, enable the extension:

```sh
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable equation-numbering/main
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. But how do I make a reference to the equation in a different cell? $\ref{label}$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See linked extension by David for example usage.

Comment: Yet did not find the automatic referencing to the equations. Any help?

Comment: what if would I like recall the equation during text?

Comment: Numbering seems to restart at "1" for each cell when I try this.

Comment: This works **if** the javascript is in a cell by itself. If you rather sensibly add it to the import cell at the top of your notebook, it fails with an error that sends you off trying to find a javascript package to somehow shoehorn into jupyter.

Comment: @PeterLeopold Yes, you shouldn't ever mix two different programming languages in the same Jupyter cell.

Comment: The javascript code used to turn on the numbering only work for Python kernel. How do we do when using the R kernel ?

Comment: I get `Javascript Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'MathJax.Hub.Config')` when I run the code in a cell.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a working example, to be entered in a markdown cell:

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{r} \equiv \begin{bmatrix}
y \\
\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:vector_ray} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

Vector **r** is defined by equation $\eqref{eq:vector_ray}$
```

It's self explanatory but here's some details:

`\label` : name describing he equation

`\tag` : the label appearing next to the equationcan be a number or letters

`\eqref` : reference to the labeled equation

This will be shown as:
[image]

Comment: This only seems to work if the eqref is in the same cell as the label - any way to make it work across the entire notebook?

Comment: \eqref works beautifully for me across the whole notebook when combining it with automatic numbering, just make a normal equation (no star in above example and no tag) and reference it as usual. I need to press "reset equation numbering" for the references to update

Comment: This works for me -- I am wondering why it shows the periods on either side of the `(1)` when referring to the equation? I would love to remove those.

Comment: @poppie, where did you "press" "reset equation numbering"? I can't seem to be able to reference an equation in a different cell....

Answer (score 2):

A quick follow-up on cross cell references for all JupyterLab users:

Since (to my knowledge) jupyter_contrib_nbextensions do not work with JupyterLab, you can just use the code from the [equation-numbering extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/equation-numbering) directly in your notebooks. This is how it **kind of** worked for me:

Cell A (code cell):

```
%%javascript
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

Cell B (code cell):

```
%%javascript
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  ["resetEquationNumbers", MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
  ["PreProcess", MathJax.Hub],
  ["Reprocess", MathJax.Hub]
);
```

Cell C (markdown cell):

```
\begin{equation}
    a = b + c \label{eq:some_eq}
\end{equation}

This is a same-cell reference to Eq. \ref{eq:some_eq}.
```

Cell D (markdown cell):

```
This is a cross cell reference to Eq. \ref{eq:some_eq}
```

For the cross-cell reference to work you have to run cell B again after running cell D (this also answers the question in @jrive's comment but appearently I don't have enugh reputation to write a comment).

I say it "kind of worked" because there is one problem: So far I could not figure out how to make the auto-numbering work properly across multiple notebooks. If I reset the numbering as described above, the equations are numbered in the same order the cells were run (not sure about this though, it sometimes seems a bit random), regardless of the notebook they belong to. So you might end up having Eq. 1, 2 and 4 in one notebook and Eq. 3 in the second. This might look somewhat weird, but at least all references link to the correct equation...
Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The only consistent way I have been able to cross-reference equations between markdown cells is to put an internal html link <a id="eq_1.1"></a> as a target before the \begin{equation} or \begin{align} in the equation.  Whatever is inside the id quotes is any arbitrary target string that isn't duplicated. However, including "eq_" helps keep the links straight.  This sets up the link target.

Then, where you want to reference this equation in another cell, insert [internal link name](#eq_1.1) in the markdown cell. Whatever is inside the [] is any arbitrary string. What is inside the () must be # followed by the target string.  You have to run both the target and the reference cell before this will work.  You can use this same method to cross-reference tables, images, etc.

Ref:

- https://ingeh.medium.com/markdown-for-jupyter-notebooks-cheatsheet-386c05aeebed
- https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4039

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Jupyter Notebook editor (I am using Anaconda right now), Edit menu, the last item 'nbextensions config'. It opens a page where you can see a list of extensions, one of which is "Equation Auto Numbering". Enable it and restart your notebook. You will see that a button appears on the top of your notebook for resetting the numbering of equations. You will need to press that button every now and then.

Comment: Conda->Jupyter->Notebook -> Edit -> "nbextensions config" simply isn't there.