# How to enable equation numbering in Markdown notebooks in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

Jupyter notebooks [support equation numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940005/704028), but I am having difficulties generating equation numbers with LaTex used in Markdown notebooks in Juyter Lab. Is this feature available, and if it is, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4):

There's an open Jupyter Lab issue for this, with a workaround (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4039)

The workaround example (from eseglem):

```
$$
\begin{align}
g &= \int_a^b f(x)dx \label{eq1}\tag{1} \\
a &= b + c \label{eq2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

See (\ref{eq1}) and (\ref{eq2})
```

Note: (as stated in the link) if you `\ref{eq1}` from another cell, it will not work. It ends up `(???)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this should be the comment from @tmaric below.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241984/equation-numbering-in-jupyter-notebooks/42940005#42940005). Kudos to @tmaric

The numbering updates as per below screenshot (in different cells):

[image]

by clicking on:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Nope, not available!

Jupyter contrib nbextensions are written for Notebooks, not Lab. You should port it over to Lab!

Comment: OK, I just got the answer on the Jupyter Lab forum that I should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940005/704028). I did and it seems to work..

Comment: For Jupyter Lab? The JavaScript snippet might work, but doubtful on the package. I haven't tried though :)