# Automatic Equation Numbering with MathJax v3.0

Tags: mathjax

I would like to [add equation numbers](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/eqnumbers.html#automatic-equation-numbering) with MathJax v3.0. I don't understand where the following code must be added :

```
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    tags: 'ams'
  }
};
```

I made a non working [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lordfc0v/) with some of my trials.

Edit : I need to number automatically all the equations.

Answer (score 3):

With the configuration `tag:'ams'` you need to wrap the equation with  `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` . So write your equation as -

```
\begin{equation}
x_1 = \sqrt(y) 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know what ams stand for ?

Comment: @Fifi: originally, AMS stood for the American Mathematical Society, but in this context it more directly references the LaTeX packages made by them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/what-does-each-ams-package-do

Answer (score 1):

Changing `ams` to `all` resolves the problem :

```
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: 'all' } }; </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lordfc0v/2/

Comment: Hi, Fifi, thanks for your answer. I would like to know that how can we add this in the `MathJax.Hub.Config`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend viewing [Equation numbering in Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241984/equation-numbering-in-jupyter-notebooks)

One of the solutions that I used from there is:

```js
%%javascript
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

Run this in another cell and the automatic numbering should be turned on.