# MathJax auto equation numbering does not work in Jupyter properly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, mathjax, jupyter-lab

I want to number the LaTeX equation, I searched internet that I shall use

```
%%javascript 
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX:{equationNumbers:{autoNumber:'all'}}
});
```

I tested with an equation also with `\eqref{}`:

```
In equation $\eqref{eq:sample}$, we find the value of an interesting integral:
\begin{equation}
  \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\,dx = \frac{\pi^4}{15}
  \label{eq:sample}{\tag{99}}
\end{equation}
```

The output in JupyterLab is 
[image]

So far everything looks alright, however I start any another cell, use `\eqref{eq:sample}` or `\ref{eq:sample}` again.

```
In equation $\eqref{eq:sample}$, we find the value of an interesting integral:
```

it turns out to be a bunch of question marks.

[image]

So I tested in Jupyter Notebook as well, as long as I call the reference from another cell, MathJax failed to link the reference.

How can I solve the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Following. I've had nothing but headaches trying to get equation numbering/reference to work properly in jupyter lab. I have spent probably 5 hours on this over the last few days. I switched to jupyter notebooks and it works fine within a cell but between cells it is fubar the numbering starts from 1 again. Starting to manually label unfortunately. :(

Comment: Note I got this working here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884029/equation-numbering-between-cells-in-jupyter-resets-to-1

I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, at the top of your notebook, put the following:

```
%%javascript
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
```

Then make equations in your Jupyter cells with things like:

```
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x} + a\dot{x} + bx = 0
\end{equation}
```

You will end up with numbered equations in your cells, but starting with 1 in each cell. To final step is you need to press the following reset equation numbering toolbar button that is in your Jupyter toolbar:

[image: reset equation numbering]

The equations all magically sort in order, across cells!

Note if you aren't seeing the reset numbering toolbar button, it means you haven't installed the equation number notebook extension. For instructions on how to install it, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940005/1886357